# IDE Gradient Toolbars

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe

Sorry for posting a non technical question :(

Look at the attached image:

[image]

How can I give the Delphi XE IDE the gradient style toolbars?

For VCL TToolbar you can set `DrawingStyle := dsGradient` for the same effect, but how may I change this for the IDE, I cannot see a option?

PS, My IDE looks blue because of a Windows theme I am using.

**Update with Result:**

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: You set `DrawingStyle` to `dsGradient`! I don't have a working sample for a complete answer, but this is the gist of it. The Delphi IDE is created using the VCL, and from a Delphi package you can access the IDE controls and change their properties to your liking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There [is an expert](http://jed-software.com/blog/?p=191) to **disable** gradients in BDS 2006. As it comes with source you can probably adapt it to XE and make it **enable** gradients.

Comment: No need to adapt, just installed the package and toggled the checkbox :)